# Synchronize accounts between two Windows computers

Tags: windows, sync, user-accounts

How can I automatically synchronize accounts between two Windows (7) computes? I'd like to keep the user-specific information in sync, that means the whole `%USERPROFILE%` folder.

Those computers may not be always connected to each other, but when they are, the accounts should synchronize automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to have the account live on a NAS, or use a domain with roaming profiles / redirected folders.

There are alternative methods like manually syncing the folder each time you are done using the computer, which is very labor intensive and counter-productive.

I think what you're really looking for is centralization, not a clone of one account in another location.